# (TCP sockets) ESP32 server recieves message, but Android client never recieves message

Tags: android, c, sockets, tcp, esp32

## The problem

I currently have a server running on an ESP32 (written in C) and a client on an android device (written in Java). When the two devices start, the two devices are connected and the client sends a message to the server. The server receives the message, prints it to console, and calls the function it is supposed to, however then it seems to hang indefinitely. I have tried changing the readline() function to read() as I heard readline() may have some unexpected results, but that also did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### The server side code (in C)

```
int tcpConnect (){
    //function variables
    const char *TAG = "TCPCONNECT";
    int sockFD = 0;
    const int PORT = 8080;
    const int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 10;
    int n = 0;
    char buffer[255] = {' '};
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    socklen_t cliLen;
    data_t data = {
        .accel_x = 0.0,
        .accel_y = 0.0,
        .accel_z = 0.0
    };

    //create the socket
    sockFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockFD < 0){
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "***COULD NOT OPEN SOCKET***\n");
    }
    else{
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "***SOCKET OPENED***\n");
    }
    
    //clear the server address
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));

    //configure the socket
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
     
    
    //bind the port to the address
    if (bind(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0){
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "***COULD NOT BIND TO PORT***\n");
    }
    else{
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "***PORT BINDED***\n");
    }
  
    //listen for incoming connections
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "***LISTENING...***\n");
    listen(sockFD, MAX_CONNECTIONS);
    cliLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    
    //accept the connections
    sockFD = accept(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &cliLen);
    if (sockFD < 0){
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "***COULD NOT ACCEPT THE SOCKET***\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("***SOCKET ACCEPTED***\n");
    }
   
   
    while(true){
        //clear the buffer to ensure there is no data left over
        memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

        //read data from the client
        n = read(sockFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (n < 0){
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "***COULD NOT READ FROM THE CLIENT***\n");
        }
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "CLIENT: %s\n", buffer);
        
        if (strcmp("QUIT", buffer) == 0){
            break;
        }

        if (strcmp("START", buffer)){   
            i2cMasterInit(&data);
        }
        else{
            printf("NOT START: %s", buffer);
        }

        //clear the buffer again
        memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    
        //copy the data from the i2cMasterInit to the buffer
        strcpy(buffer, "okay"); 

        //send the data to the client
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "***TRYING TO WRITE***\n");
        n = write(sockFD, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        //This prints out 4, I know that represents the size being sent, but not sure if it means it was actually sent and the android app never receives it, or if it wasn't actually sent
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "***N: %d***\n", n);
        if (n < 0){
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "***COULD NOT WRITE TO THE CLIENT***\n");
        }
    }
    shutdown(sockFD, 0);
    close(sockFD);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

### The server side output

```
I (5328) TCPCONNECT: ***SOCKET OPENED***

I (5328) TCPCONNECT: ***PORT BINDED***

I (5338) TCPCONNECT: ***LISTENING...***

***SOCKET ACCEPTED***
I (7358) TCPCONNECT: CLIENT: START

///Results from another function
I (7358) i2cMasterInit: accel_x:    39.696362 accel_y:  0.031720 accel_z:   9.745360

I (7458) TCPCONNECT: ***TRYING TO WRITE***

I (7458) TCPCONNECT: ***N: 4***
```

## Client side code (Java)

### Function to start the client thread

```
public void run(){
        try{

            this.sockFD = new Socket(HOSTNAME, PORT);
            this.status = true;
            while(true) {
                sendMessage("START");
                serverMessage = getMessage();
                Log.d(TAG, "SERVER: " + serverMessage);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "***COULD NOT CONNECT TO HOST " + e + "***");
            this.status = false;
        }
    }
```

### Function to write message to server (seems to work as intended based on server output)

```
public void sendMessage(String message){
        try {
            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(sockFD.getOutputStream());
            pr.println(message);
            pr.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "***COULD NOT SEND MESSAGE TO HOST " + e +"***");
        }
    }
```

### Function to read from the server (this is the function I believe the problem is located)

```
public String getMessage(){
        String serverMessage = "DEFAULT";
        try{
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(sockFD.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
            serverMessage = bf.readLine();
            Log.d("GETMESSAGE", "SERVER:" + serverMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "***COULD NOT READ MESSAGE FROM HOST " + e +"***");
        }
        return serverMessage;
    }
```

## Java Logcat

Honestly there doesn't seem to be anything of note in the logs, this is the only line that may be of use

```
tagSocket(111) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```

Please let me know if any additional information is needed, thank you.

Comment: (1) You're reading lines but you aren't sending lines. Add a newline to the message sent by the server. (2) Don't create a new `BufferedReader` or `InputStreamReader` for every message. Use the same ones for the life of the socket. Ditto the `PrintWriter`. (3) you are ignoring the case when `read()` returns zero. This can be used to get rid of the QUIT message altogether. (4) None of the `memset()` calls is necessary. Just make proper use of `n` returned by `read()`. (5) Don't assume that the message received by the C code is null-terminated. Java doesn't do that. Again that's what `n` is for.